# python: performance enhancement shrinking image

Tags: python, image, performance, numpy

I have written the following code to scale an image to 50%.  However, it took this algorithm 65 seconds to shrink a 3264x2448 image.  Can someone who understands numpy explain why this algorithm is so inefficient and suggest more efficient changes?

```
def shrinkX2(im):
    X, Y = im.shape[1] / 2, im.shape[0] / 2
    new = np.zeros((Y, X, 3))
    for y in range(Y):
        for x in range(X):
            new[y, x] = im[2*y:2*y + 2, 2*x:2*x + 2].reshape(4, 3).mean(axis=0)
    return new
```

Comment: @Divakar I'm using cv2 to import a color image in the shape (Y, X, 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the text of the question, it seems you are shrinking the image by `50%` and by the code it seems, you are doing it in blocks. We can reshape to split each of the two axes of the `2D` input by lengths as the required block sizes to get a `4D` array and then compute `mean` along the axes corresponding to the block sizes, like so -

```
def block_mean(im, BSZ):
    m,n = im.shape[:2]
    return im.reshape(m//BSZ[0],BSZ[0],n//BSZ[1],BSZ[1],-1).mean((1,3))
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: im = np.random.randint(0,9,(6,8,3))

In [45]: im[:2,:2,:].mean((0,1)) # average of first block across all 3 channels
Out[45]: array([3.25, 3.75, 3.5 ])

In [46]: block_mean(im, BSZ=(2,2))
Out[46]: 
array([[[3.25, 3.75, 3.5 ],
        [4.  , 4.5 , 3.75],
        [5.75, 2.75, 5.  ],
        [3.  , 3.5 , 3.25]],

       [[4.  , 5.5 , 5.25],
        [6.25, 1.75, 2.  ],
        [4.25, 2.75, 1.75],
        [2.  , 4.75, 3.75]],

       [[3.25, 3.5 , 5.25],
        [4.25, 1.5 , 5.25],
        [3.5 , 3.5 , 4.25],
        [0.75, 5.  , 5.5 ]]])
```

Comment: ok, so this looks like it would work for a grayscale image.  What about with color (r, g, b) channels?

Comment: Oh my goodness!  Your code takes less than 2 seconds!  What was I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jonathan Looping with NumPy arrays isn't the best thing to do. We are using NumPy array supported functions and reshaping to make it vectorized and hence gaining performance.

Comment: Hey, I have one other function that I would love for you to look at and see if you could make it a little faster.  I will post the link here once I post the question.

Comment: Ok, if you would like, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268522/python-performance-image-slicing-numpy