# python: performance image slicing numpy

Tags: python, arrays, image, performance, numpy

I have a function that does the task I need, but is not very efficient.  The function takes a color image represented by a numpy array and creates a new array of every complete, 3x3 slice of my image. At the end I reshape it for my desired purpose, effectively reshaping to (columns*rows, 3*3*3 slice)  Here is the code:

```
def get_kernels(im, k_size):
    X, Y = im.shape[1] + 1 - k_size, im.shape[0] + 1 - k_size
    new = np.zeros((Y, X, k_size, k_size, 3))
    for y in range(Y):
        for x in range(X):
            new[y, x] = im[y:y + k_size, x:x + k_size]
    return new.reshape(X * Y, k_size ** 2 * 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scikit-image's `view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to create those sliding windows and then we need to permute axes and reshape -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def get_kernels_vectorized(im, k_size):
    X, Y = im.shape[1] + 1 - k_size, im.shape[0] + 1 - k_size
    new = view_as_windows(im,(k_size,k_size,1))[...,0].transpose(0,1,3,4,2)
    return new.reshape(X * Y, k_size ** 2 * 3)
```

**Explanation on usage of `view_as_windows`**

The idea with `view_as_windows` is that we feed in the input arg `window_shape` as a tuple of length same as the number of dimensions in the input array whose sliding windows are needed. Also, the axes along which we don't need to *slide* are fed as `1s`. So, the input value for `window_shape` here is `(k_size, k_size, 1)` as the last axis is of color channels, along which we don't need to *slide*.

Sample run for verification -

```
In [186]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: im = np.random.randint(0,9,(6,8,3))

In [189]: out1 = get_kernels(im, k_size=3)

In [190]: out2 = get_kernels_vectorized(im, k_size=3)

In [191]: np.array_equal(out1, out2)
Out[191]: True
```

Timings on `3264x2448 image` with `kernel size = 3` -

```
In [177]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: im = np.random.randint(0,9,(3264,2448,3))

In [178]: %timeit get_kernels(im, k_size=3)
1 loop, best of 3: 5.46 s per loop

In [179]: %timeit get_kernels_vectorized(im, k_size=3)
1 loop, best of 3: 327 ms per loop
```

`16x+` speedup here.

Comment: It's over 30x faster for me!  Does np.allclose just make sure that the outputs are identical?

Comment: @Jonathan We need to use `np.array_equal` for that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The use-case is not entirely clear to me.

It might be possible you are asking for something like [skimage](http://scikit-image.org/)'s [view_as_windows](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows). If that's the case, either use it or learn from it (numpy.lib.stride_tricks).

With the correct input, it's a *view* (no new array will be created) and will be as fast as it gets!